# Pretty format of XML generated by Simple (Java Lib)

Tags: java, xml, serialization

I am facing a problem regarding readability and cross-platform issues.

We are generating our UI on the fly, using certain classes and subclasses. For an example, I will use basic elements (not UI ones), but I think the "problem" should be obvious.

I am asking IF there is any configuration switch in Simple (http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php) to achieve the desired result. As said, its about readability for another platform, if I would only have to target JAVA, I would not care about the look and feel of the XML.

So, in my example, I serialize a simple class, the result is:

```
<GuiElementExamples>
   <LastCreated>2012-04-15 16:48:59.813 CEST</LastCreated>
   <NonGuiObject>
      <objectBase class="objects.single.simple.StringObject" _value="">
         <_readonly>false</_readonly>
      </objectBase>
      <objectBase class="objects.single.simple.StringProperty">
         <_items>
            <object class="objects.single.simple.StringObject" _value="Label">
               <_readonly>true</_readonly>
            </object>
            <object class="objects.single.simple.StringObject" _value="">
               <_readonly>false</_readonly>
            </object>
         </_items>
         <_readonly>false</_readonly>
      </objectBase>
   </NonGuiObject>
</GuiElementExamples>
```

What I would love to have (I will create it by hand as an example), is this:

```
<GuiElementExamples>
   <LastCreated>2012-04-15 16:48:59.813 CEST</LastCreated>
   <NonGuiObject>
      <StringObject _value="">
         <_readonly>false</_readonly>
      </StringObject>
      <StringProperty>
         <_items>
            <StringObject _value="Label">
               <_readonly>true</_readonly>
            </StringObject>
            <StringObject _value="">
               <_readonly>false</_readonly>
            </StringObject>
         </_items>
         <_readonly>false</_readonly>
      </StringProperty>
   </NonGuiObject>
</GuiElementExamples>
```

I KNOW there will be NO clashes in class names, and one option I could use is a simple search and replace script, but maybe there is an option to configure "simple" in a way to export the stuff as shown above.

I am aware that there would be no way to DESERIALIZE stuff in the format above, without running e.g. the mentioned script before, because without the fully qualified class name, simple can't know which object to create..

Thanks for any help or workaround ideas,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Like always, after writing it, and going back to the docs, I found it :-)
It is the last entry on the tutorial page, in my example this does the trick:
**EDIT This does not work with more then one element, dont ask me why EDIT**

```
  @ElementListUnion({@ElementList(entry = "StringObject", type = StringObject.class)})
  private ArrayList<T> _items = new ArrayList<T>();
```

The solution I used is a little bit more complicated, but get the job done. I will post the source here to point you in the right direction (ObjectBase is the base class of all my objects I want to "rename" the way described above):

```
public class FormatVisitor implements Visitor
{
    private static ILogger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(FormatVisitor.class);
    @Override
    public void read(Type type, NodeMap<InputNode> strings) throws Exception
    {

    }

    public void write(Type type, NodeMap<OutputNode> node)
    {
        OutputNode element = node.getNode();


        Class javaType = type.getType();

        if (ObjectBase.class.isAssignableFrom(javaType))
        {
            _logger.Verbose("Old name was " + element.getName());
            element.setName(javaType.getSimpleName());
            _logger.Verbose("Changing name to " + javaType.getSimpleName());
        }

        try
        {
            String className =  element.getAttributes().get("class").getValue();
            Class localClass = Class.forName(className);
            boolean shouldShortenName = ObjectBase.class.isAssignableFrom(localClass);
            if (shouldShortenName)
            {
                element.getAttributes().remove("class");
                element.setName(localClass.getSimpleName());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }


        if (ObjectBase.class.isAssignableFrom(javaType))
        {
            element.setName(type.getType().getSimpleName());
        }

    }


}
```